# Is there a better approach on this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query finds the directors of all shops. I think that there is a simpler solution to this, something that I will prefer to use. Thank you.

```
SELECT s.ShopID, (EmployeeName+' '+EmployeeSurname) AS FullName FROM shop AS s
JOIN WorksOn AS w ON s.ShopID = w.ShopID
JOIN employee AS e ON w.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
JOIN director AS d ON e.EmployeeID = d.EmployeeID
```

TABLES

```
employee : EmployeeID, EmployeeName,EmployeeSurname
shop: ShopID, Name, Address
WorksOn: EmployeeID, ShopID
director: EmployeeID
```

Comment: Looks fine, but the data retrieved does not really make sense. Do you want to show all shops? or all shops + all empoyees? Why do you join director table then?

Comment: @user194076 he joins directors table as a filter for directors.

Comment: What it does, it shows the shop id and the full name of the employee who is a director. Even though I get the correct result I think that there is a better way to do this. Yes like Karolis said

Comment: I think the only way to make it simpler is try to find other tables in a database which let you do a query more direct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>It's a very simple query. According to information you provided I don't see anything simpler.</strike>

Pardon. Yes you can do it in 2 joins:

```
SELECT 
    w.ShopID, (EmployeeName+' '+EmployeeSurname) AS FullName 
FROM 
    WorksOn AS w
    JOIN employee AS e ON w.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
    JOIN director AS d ON e.EmployeeID = d.EmployeeID
```

Comment: I guess it has to have a solution with 2 join only. This is what I am trying to do

Comment: The only way you can do 2 joins - Place bit column "IsDirector" in your employee column.

Comment: @Sampas Yeah. @user194076 is right. If you want something simpler, then you need to change the structure of your database.

Answer (score 1):

THere are a few practical concerns with that query. They might not be issues depending upon how you are using it. But, I'm guessing that in your case you aren't satisfied. So here are my issues:

1. if there isn't a director etc for a store you get no results for that store. LEFT JOIN it.
2. if there are 2 directors and 2 employees, you'll get 4 records. So, you can fix that by having separate queries or by GROUP BY and GROUP_CONCAT or some other aggregate function.

Comment: How does it change using GROUP BY and GROUP_CONCAT ? It's a query for personal use, not something important though but I am trying to work it at the best.

Comment: If you group by Shop, then it would give you only one record for that shop and then you can group_concat(employee_id), group_concat(director_id) and you have all your data in one record. if you have a large store with 200 employees and 20 directors that would end up have 4000 records without GROUP BY or separate queries.